# How to use @nuxt/image with image from assets

Tags: image, nuxt.js

I try to use @nuxt/image with image from assets folder; when using image from static folder or external url, the image is optimised as well; but when on using it on image from assets like below:

```html
<nuxt-img
    src="~assets/img/Icone-accueil/row_left.svg"
    alt=""
    class="float-left margin-fleche"
    quality="30"
/>
```

I have this result in my html

```html
<img src="/_ipx/q_30/_nuxt/assets/img/Icone-accueil/row_left.svg" alt="" class="float-left margin-fleche">
```

but the image doesn't appear

Comment: Your example is using a .svg file, I would not think that nuxt-img would do anything there?

Answer (score 9):

As per [Nuxt Image doc](https://image.nuxtjs.org/api/options#dir), default direcrtory for images is */static*, you can change it by update **nuxt.config** file as below.

> e.g,
>
> ```
> image: {
>     dir: 'assets/images',
> },
> ```

Now you can rewrite as,

```
<nuxt-img
    src="/Icone-accueil/row_left.svg"
    alt=""
    class="float-left margin-fleche"
    quality="30"
/>
```

Comment: when run build the assets directory images not working in nuxt3

Comment: It should be working with same config in Nuxt2 and Nuxt3. check your nuxt-image version if still issue occurs. I have added links for both versions.

[Nuxt2](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nuxt-2-3gtpqm?file=%2FREADME.md)
[Nuxt3](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nuxt-3-zhz7kh?file=%2Fnuxt.config.ts)

Answer (score 3):

From nuxt documentation:

> Inside your ‍‍`vue` templates, if you need to link to your assets
> directory use `~/assets/your_image.png` with a slash before assets.

In your case:

```html
<nuxt-img
    src="~/assets/img/Icone-accueil/row_left.svg"
    alt=""
    class="float-left margin-fleche"
    quality="30"
/>
```

Another quote from nuxt:

> When working with dynamic images you will need to use require

```html
<img :src="require(`~/assets/img/${image}.jpg`)" />
```

In your case check this out:

```html
<nuxt-img
    :src="require(`~/assets/img/Icone_accueil/row_left.svg`)"
    alt=""
    class="float-left margin-fleche"
    quality="30"
/>
```

Comment: i return error 404 IPX: File not found: E:\projet-michel\noah-voyage-git\noah-voyages-version-2\static\_nuxt\assets\img\Icone-accueil\row_left.svg

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Not sure why, but are you sure your settings are not set to work with IPX: https://image.nuxtjs.org/providers/ipx ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `@nuxt/image` with images from the `assets/` folder does not work in Nuxt v2.

The following is from the `@nuxt/image` [documentation](https://image.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/providers#local-images):

> Images should be stored in the `static/` directory of your project.
>
> For example, when using `<nuxt-img src="/nuxt-icon.png" />`, it should
> be placed in `static/` folder under the path `static/nuxt-icon.png`.
>
> Image stored in the `assets/` directory are not proccessed with Nuxt
> Image because those images are managed by webpack.

Comment: For some reason following the 'installation' section of the docs is breaking my code. I'm using nuxt 3 and I believe that the docs are for the older version.
Precisely, I did this in my nuxt.config.ts
1. yarn add --dev @nuxt/image -> then -> added "@nuxt/image" to my nuxt.config.ts modules. 
Also, I'm new to nuxt so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: In Nuxt 3, it needs to be the ~/public directory.

Answer (score 2):

For Nuxt3 users whom are using the edge version, which is v1, of nuxt/image,
if you are self-hosting, place images in the 'public' directory as opposed to 'static'.

Quote from v1 docs:

> With default provider, you should put /nuxt-icon.png inside public/ directory for >Nuxt 3 make the above example work.

v0 (Nuxt2)
`/static/images/myImage.jpg`
v1 (Nuxt3)
`/public/images/myImage.jpg`

Then, access images in the same way others have described.  Nuxt/image v1 does not seem able to read a dir named static and of course doesn't read assets as that is used by Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<img :src="require(`~/assets/image.jpeg`)"
      alt=""
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must create a **custom** **Provider**.
this code worked for me:

```
nuxt.config.ts

image:{
  providers:{
    customProvider:{
       name: 'assetsProvider',
       provider: '~/providers/assets-provider.ts', // must be created
       options:{
         baseURL: "/_nuxt/assets"
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

for more information click on link
https://image.nuxt.com/advanced/custom-provider